# SQL 2 Left Join in one query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2, table1.column2 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 (ON table1.column1=table2.column2)
```

What I want to do is add another left join to the table but also to count in that left join data like:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2, table1.column2, COUNT(table3.column1) 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column1=table2.column2 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.column1=table3.column1
```

the code does not seems to work, what could be wrong?

Comment: "Does not seem to work" isn't a valid problem description.  Are you getting an error?  Incorrect results?  Something else?  MySQL and SQL Server are two different products (with some very different behavior), which do you actually have?  Since we're doing aggregation, we also need to know the distribution of rows (since `COUNT(...)` may return incorrect results otherwise); what does the data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is an aggregate function - you can't mix it with single-row functions without a `group by` clause. One way around this is to join on a subquery instead of directly on `table3` and apply the `group by` there:

```
SELECT    table1.column1, table2.column2, table1.column2, cnt
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column2 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   column1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     table3
           GROUP BY column1) table3 ON table1.column1=table3.column1
```